# How to properly terminate both ends of Cat6 patch cable (because of swapping side pairs)?

Tags: data-wiring, ethernet

I'm using Legrand® CAT 6 RJ45 Plugs - 10 Pack (Model Number: AC3460V0) to terminate my new network cables.  They have a *separator*-insert (visible below in one of the plugs) and an *order*-insert (which goes under the pins).  So far one of the cable ends had a keystone jack and everything was very smooth, because pairs happened to be positioned in "proper" order - easy for unraveling and inserting into jacks and/or flattening for plugs.

The first 2ft patch cable surprised me with an unexpected hiccup:  on one of the ends orange and brown pairs needed to be swapped in position, but that created a bulge (stacking 4 pairs on each other), which prevented placing the separator-insert.
I googled for instructions, but most how-to pictures are from Cat3 days, and at best links mention Cat6's spline, but not this effect, *which is unavoidable if you think about it*.  It may not be an issue for Cat5, but in Cat6 the spline separates pairs into their quadrants and keeps them in that order up until the very end of the cable!  I'm using the TIA-568B standard, though it really shouldn't matter - simple topology shows at one end this will happen either way.

I ended up with wires in proper order, but tester shows pairs 3-6 and 7-8 open (do I read it right?):

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

I checked connectivity pin-to-pin with a multimeter - that seemed ok.  I may have nicked a pair, but methinks that could've created a short, not an open connection.
I shouldn't remove too much of the jacket (so it will be grabbed upon by the plug), and I shouldn't untwist the pairs more than ~1.2cm (.5").  I get that I need to redo this plug, but first **what is the right way to swap the side pairs?**

How do the professionals deal with this?

Comment: Professionals wire jacks, and purchase (or their customers purchase) patch cables, speaking as a professional in this line of work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented, we mostly don't.

As for what you are trying to do, flip the connector with respect to the cable, (or the cable with respect to the connector, makes no difference) and you'll find it's just as easy as the first one.

*The data sheet for this product is **extremely underwhelming** but a common problem with "making your own patch cables" is that **most** plugs are compatible with stranded wire only, and making a patch cable from solid in-wall wire is unreliable since the stranded wire contacts don't work well with solid wire. In this case the **extremely underwhelming** data sheet simply doesn't specify anything about that.*

Comment: *we mostly don't* - that's it exactly. Even retail you can get them in bulk for a couple of dollars each, so it simply doesn't pay. If they are in the wall then the only right thing to do is to wire up jacks anyway. If they are not in the wall, just figure out what size you need and order them all ready to use. I try to keep plenty of short/medium length on hand plus a couple of long (50' or 100') just in case I need a temporary installation that would otherwise be in the wall. But make em myself? Pretty much never. Bought the tools (years ago, CAT 3 or 5) never use them.

Comment: Yup - unless you're paying highway robbery at Staples, *et al,* the connectors cost more than a whole patch cable, tested and ready to roll. Not to mention the price of my time when I'm doing it for hire...

Comment: Just flip, huh? D'oh! Thank you, that's what many-many years of experience has! :) 
Good point on solid vs. stranded wire. Out of 15 cables made this one is the first with the problem. To save my rep at least a bit, this is meant to be a patch for the network closet - I'll plug it in once and move no more. 
Can you recommend good plugs? What should I look for in their specs?

Comment: Meh, try the ones you have, you might get it working if you're trying to cheap it out with what you have. That wire-type incompatibility can be a source of problems with connections, which is why I bring it up. You can always buy a patch if it won't work or fails later. I understand the "but it won't be moving" argument, and what I look for in that case is plugs that *explicitly claim to be solid, or solid and stranded compatible.* But seriously, a factory-built patch is generally cheaper than new plugs, or a hunk of stranded cable, and more reliable.

Comment: Got it, thanks again! Will keep an eye on the plugs in case of connection issues. Wish I knew that before buying 1000ft of cable :)

Comment: One thing I dislike about patch cables is that they usually come *folded* (instead of *coiled*), and it's very hard to straighten these kinks - I'm a neat-freak ))

Comment: Plenty of patch vendors sell them coiled.